# What's the trick to use otool on the mac?

Tags: iphone, otool

I want to see the headers of an application. I try this:

> myMac:~ me$ /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/otool [-fahlLDtdorSTMRIHvVcXm] /Developer/Platforms/TheIPhoneApplication -f

The file is definitely there.

but it tells me "no file found". Any idea?

Comment: [-fahlLDtdorSTMRIHvVcXm] means that you can use any of those options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[-fahlLDtdorSTMRIHvVcXm] is definitely wrong here
I believe you had something like this in mind:

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/otool -f /Developer/Platforms/TheIPhoneApplication
```

Comment: great! yes that seems to be the solution. However, when I do that I just get no message. It seems it accesses the file now, but after sending the command just nothing more is happening. Any idea?