# how to use otool

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, otool

apple suggested me to use "strings" or "otool" to dect the private api (isinf) in my code , I am totally newbie  so any help how to use those tools

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229018/whats-the-trick-to-use-otool-on-the-mac, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842357/how-does-apple-know-you-are-using-private-api and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863764/how-to-detect-avoid-the-use-of-private-apis-in-third-party-libraries

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Open Terminal ( Ctrl + Space -> Type 'Terminal')..

and print example:

```
otool -MVv yourlib.a
```

for help:

```
otool --help
```

Comment: This set of parameters are no longer supported by otool. Would you care to explain what did they mean?

Comment: @leolobato according to the documentation, `-M` used to "print the module table of a dynamic shared library"

Comment: FYI: `warning: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: -M functionality obsolete
OVERVIEW: llvm object file dumper`

Comment: You can use `otool -tvV` or `nm` to get some private info

Answer (score 13):

I use `nm` to inspect my binaries. Usage can't be simpler:

```
 nm <filename>
```

It will list some weird memory-address or whatever, then a visibility character and lastly the symbol. T is public, but check out the man page of `nm` to find out more about this.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to open up the terminal.

Comment: could you give me more details

Comment: you know how to start up a terminal? Just type "nm" and then you binary and you will see a long list of symbols. You can then grep for stuff like so "nm <file> | grep isinf"

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, the otool tools is alternative to the objdump on the Windows.
You should open Terminal and print example:

```
$ man otool  //Usage for otool
```

If you want to disassemble a file, Just type like this:

```
$ otool -tV filename
```